# Can the Access Subform control property "show page header and page footer" be set using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

The "show page header and page footer" property appears in the properties panel but I can't find it on the MSDN help pages: [SubForm.Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821725.aspx)

How can I set the value of this property using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of that property is *ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter*.  In order to access its value, you must reference it via the subform control's `Properties` collection:

```vb
? Forms!Form2!Child0.Properties("ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter").Value
False
```

However, if you want to change that property value, the form must be open in Design View:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acDesign
Forms!Form2!Child0.Properties("ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter").Value = True
? Forms!Form2!Child0.Properties("ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter").Value
True
```

If you attempt to alter its value when the form is not in Design View, Access throws error #2136, *"To set this property, open the form or report in Design view."*

Comment: Thanks. I suspected as much but I've never used the properties collection before.  Have you any idea why is is not listed on the MSDN helppages?  Are there other properties like this that can be access in the properteis collection that are not on the MSDN help pages?

Comment: No idea why it's not listed.  I never paid attention to *ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter* until I saw your question.  I'm not sure about other properties.  If you want to investigate, you can list the names of all the properties in the subform control's `Properties` collection with this as one line in the Immediate window: `for each prp in forms!YourForm!YourSubformControl.Properties : ? prp.name : next`  That is what I used to find *ShowPageHeaderAndPageFooter*.

Comment: I though you might say that... I think MS should be paying someone to find  all their missing documentation for them!    That might be a long list!   Thanks for your help.